# Installing SPE 4.7.2/5.0 on Sitecore XP 9

Tags: powershell-extensions, installation

I am trying to install SXA 1.8.0 on Sitecore 9.1 environment (my local pc as testing) but I cannot install Sitecore Powershell Extension 4.7.2/5.0 which is required to be installed before SXA installation.

The error messages are shown as below:

```
ManagedPoolThread #3 16:37:48 ERROR Error installing 
items/master/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Definitions/Elements/PowerShell 
Experience Buttons/Chrome Type/of Type/{F5D1B95B-30D3-4738-B41E-6884517CB485}/en/1/xml
Exception: System.NullReferenceException
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
Location Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataProvider.ResolvePathRec(String[] path, PathCache cache, CallContext context)
Location Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.DataProvider.ResolvePath(String itemPath, CallContext context, DataProviderCollection providers)
Location Sitecore.Nexus.Data.DataCommands.ResolvePathCommand.​‏⁮⁯⁪⁫‬‎⁯⁪‏‭‮‬‎‫⁭⁬‭‍‮‎⁪⁪⁯⁪⁮‭‪‮⁭⁪‍⁭‌⁭‌⁭‬‫‮(String , Database )
Location Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.Execute()
Location Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemProvider.GetItem(String itemPath, Language language, Version version, Database database, SecurityCheck securityCheck)
Location Sitecore.ContentTesting.Pipelines.ItemProvider.GetItem.GetItemUnderTestProcessor.Process(GetItemArgs args)
Location (Object , Object )
Location Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
Location Sitecore.Data.Managers.DefaultItemManager.GetItem(String itemPath, Language language, Version version, Database database, SecurityCheck securityCheck)
Location Sitecore.Data.Managers.DefaultItemManager.GetItem(String itemPath, Language language, Version version, Database database)
Location Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemManager.GetItem(String itemPath, Language language, Version version, Database database)
Location Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemReference.GetItem()
Location Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.GetTargetItem(ItemReference reference, Boolean& ignorePathCollision)
Location Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.GetVersionInstallMode(PackageEntry entry, ItemReference reference, XmlVersionParser parser, ItemInstallerContext context, Boolean& removeVersions)
Location Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.InstallEntry(PackageEntry entry)
```

Has anyone faced this issue before?

Comment: For the records only, is this instance fresh new or it already has a few modules installed?

Comment: This instance is fresh other than a language pack (Japanese) was installed.

Comment: Can you please double check your SQL Server version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was caused by incompatibility of SQL Server version.
I was using SQL Server 2016 instead of 2017.
After migrating from SQL Server 2016 to 2017 (even after installing Sitecore 9.x, it fixed this issue).